# how do i rewrite as a algebraic expression

Tags: trigonometric-integrals

please rewrite this trigonometric expression $\cos(\tan^{-1}(u)+\sin^{-1}(v))$ as an algebraic expression? I tried the sum differences method and could get no further

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

use these formulas

- $$\cos(A+B)=\cos(A)\cos(B)-\sin(A)\sin(B)$$
- $$1+\tan^2(X)=\frac{1}{\cos^2(X)}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Set $\theta=\arctan u$, $\varphi=\arcsin v$. Use the addition formula for $\;\cos(\theta+\varphi)$.

This will require you to compute $\cos\theta$, $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\varphi$, $\sin \varphi$. 
We can easily deduce the squares of these numbers.

For instance, $\cos^2\theta=\dfrac1{1+\tan^2\theta}=\dfrac1{1+u^2},\;$ so $\;\cos \theta=\dfrac{\pm1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}$. To determine the sign, you must remember the definition:
$$\theta=\arctan u\stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff}\tan\theta=u\;\textbf{and}\;-\frac\pi2<\theta<\frac\pi2, $$
so the sign is  `+`. Then you have also $\sin \theta$ at once:
$$\sin\theta=\tan\theta\cos\theta=\frac u{\sqrt{1+u^2}}.$$
Do similarly for $\varphi$.